# Amend datatable options in renderDataTable not using JS()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a sample Shiny dashboard in the R Studio console. I have some tables:

```
output$summary_table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    # some code here
})
```

When this table gets displayed it has things like pagination and a search box. I would like to remove those but the documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/option/) seems to all be based on editing JS/html e.g.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "paging": false
} );
```

Is there a way to do this within `DT::datatable({})` instead? I would not know how to integrate this with my R code as is? Or is it simple and I'm just not getting the intended use?

I would like to remove pagination and search box.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) link for DT datatable styling and options in shiny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
datatable(iris,options=list(bFilter=FALSE, bPaginate=FALSE))
```

or to show only table:

```
datatable(iris,options = list(dom='t',bPaginate=FALSE))
```

Full Example Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui= basicPage(dataTableOutput("tab"))

server= function(input, output,session) {

  output$tab <-  DT::renderDataTable({datatable(iris,options=list(bFilter=FALSE, bPaginate=FALSE))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example it's hard to help! Have a look at my edit: **Full Example Code**, no warning appears

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks it's working now.Out of curiosity I looked at the documentation. How did you know to prepend "b" as in bFilter) in the options?

Comment: Actually i had the same problem long time ago and researched quite deeply, well if you have a look at the pure `datatable` documentation (as for example here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4634/disable-bpaginate-and-blengthchange, you can notice that `b` appears in front of the option as in `bPaginate`